# Sorting an object with object.entries

Tags: javascript

I have an object of data which I'd like to sort. I'm running the following object through `Object.entries(data).map()` to display it on my Front-End, but I'd like to maintain a specific order. Right now it seems that the order is somewhat random. I'm using `.map` to display a number of React components so sorting after the map doesn't seem to be possible.

```
const data = {
  rent: {
   value: '100'
    },
  },
  legal: {
    value: '300'
  },
  misc: {
    value: '300'
    },
 horse: {
   value: '400'
   }
  },
};
```

Ideally `rent` should be the first item when it's mapped out, and `misc` should be the last one. I've tried using `.sort()` but I don't seem to be having any luck.

What is the right way to achieve this? I assume some combination of `Object.entries(data).sort().map()` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I'll explain with a snippet soon (FYI, the sort function takes as an argument a compare function...)

Comment: You can't guarantee order of object properties. You would have to use a different data type as a middle-man.

Comment: If you know the keys should be an a certain order, why not make an array of the keys in the order you want, iterate over that array, and process each key in turn? `['rent', 'legal', 'horse', 'misc'].forEach(function(key){ ..do stuff with data[key]... })`

Comment: JS objects are key / value systems, there is nothing to sort

Comment: I know you can't guarantee the order of object properties, and I don't mind converting the data to an array before hand. I'm just looking for a way to do that programmatically so I can guarantee the correct order in the `.map`

Comment: I'm confused... are you trying to sort by value or by key?

Comment: "Ideally **rent** should be the first item when it's mapped out, and **misc** should be the last one."  where is the order ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following will sort them so that **rent** is first **misc** is last and the rest are alphabetically

```js
const data = {
  rent: {
    value: '100'
  },
  legal: {
    value: '300'
  },
  misc: {
    value: '300'
  },
  horse: {
    value: '400'
  }
};

function rent_ab_misc(obj=[]){
  return Object.entries(obj).sort(([key1], [key2]) => {
    if (key1 === 'misc' || key2==='rent') return 1;
    if (key1 === 'rent' || key2 === 'misc') return -1;
    return key1 > key2
  })
}

// useage
const output = rent_ab_misc(data).map(([key,item])=>`<div>${key}:${item.value}</div>`)

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide a compare function to your `sort` function, if wishing to use `Object.entries`:

```js
const data = {
  rent: {
   value: '100'
  },
  legal: {
    value: '300'
  },
  misc: {
    value: '201'
 },
 horse: {
   value: '400'
 }
};

function compare(a, b){
  if( a[1].value < b[1].value ){
    return -1
  } else if( a[1].value > b[1].value ){
    return 1;
  } 
  return 0;
}
console.log(Object.entries(data).sort(compare))
```

The code above becomes much cleaner if the original data structure is an array of objects:

```js
const data = [
  { key: 'rent', value: '100' },
  { key: 'legal', value: '300' },
  { key: 'misc', value: '201' },
  { key: 'horse', value: '400' }
];

let sorted = data.sort(({key:k1, value:v1}, {key:k2, value:v2}) => {
  if( v1 < v2 ){
    return -1;
  } else if( v1 > v2 ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
})
console.log('sorted arr', sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain a consistent order, use an array of objects instead of a single object.  The property order of an object is not guaranteed.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'rent', value: '100' },
  { name: 'legal', value: '300' },
  { name: 'misc', value: '300' },
  { name: 'horse', value:'400' }
];

const sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : a.name > b.name ? 1 : 0;
});

console.log(sortedData);
```